# Use a specific class depending on bullet with Markdown/Pandoc

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I use Markdown to write my training documents, and I convert them to HTML using Pandoc.

I'd like to have a class bullet using the classic `*` character, and having the logo + (cool!) and - (not cool) using bullets `+`and `-`.

Currently I have no differences in the output HTML. How could I add a class depending on the bullet?

Comment: At this moment, the best solution I have is to write a groovy script that transform some markdown elements to pure HTML with its classes, and then I run pandoc. I would like a way that does not introduce  another technology.

Comment: I thought about javascript/jQuery wich could be ok, but it's executed after pandoc in the way I use it. So the bullet differenciations has disappeared when javascript is enabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get HTML `class` attributes out of Pandoc, you have to set these attributes explicitly in the input files. This is supported only for [code blocks](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#delimited-code-blocks), and does not work automatically.

To get classes for lists, you need to modify Pandoc to output them.

In [`src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/HTML.hs`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/b808655b2b48cdcbb7591695dd64db455252970e/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/HTML.hs), attributes for code blocks are generated in `attrsToHtml`, called from `blockToHtml` or `inlineToHtml`.
You would have to extend `unordList` to generate an attribute and to call `attrsToHtml` on it.

(The absence of the [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell) tag indicates that this might not be the solution you are looking for ...)

Comment: I think I will have to pay someone to do this :) Thanks for looking deep in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean list bullets you can wrap the list in a div with a class and use a corresponding CSS selector:

```
<div class="styledlist">
+   foo
+   bar
+   baz
</div>
```

will give you HTML like this:

```
<div class="styledlist">
<ul>
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
<li>baz</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and you can use a CSS selector like this:

```
span.styledlist ul { ... }
```

Not the prettiest Markdown or HTML but it works.